# Boot-repair commands not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: boot-failure

I recently had problems with my ubuntu partition (after the battery died), I managed to fix them by running ubuntu from usb and run gparted.
It worked I can access my files on the partition by running ubuntu from usb.
But when I restart the computer, after selecting ubuntu in Grub,
I get a black screen with a white underscore.

I googled the problem, and tried to solve it by setting nomodeset,
but it didn't work.

Next I wanted to try to fix Grub using boot-repair, I clicked on 'Recommended repair',
it tells me to type the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda5" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda5" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda5" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub-common
```

But when running the second command, I get this error:

```
dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 3 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
```

I didn't edit /etc/environment (or any other files), this is what it looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
RUNNING_UNDER_GDM="yes"
```

(I also tried this with the boot-repair CD, but it gave the same errors)

I have no idea how to fix this.
I'm running dualboot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, Windows boots fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means your system has a deep dpkg problem.
If I were you, I would simply reinstall the system files this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal do the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Search for the line: "quiet splash" and change it to  "quiet splash nomodeset"; then,

```
sudo update-grub

sudo echo FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: When I run sudo updat-grub I get this:

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).

Comment: Ok. First run: mount dev/sda5 then run those commands. I'm assuming  sda5 is your ubuntu hard drive.

Comment: I already tried that but then i got this error:
mount: can't find dev/sda5 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab;

But I managed to mount it by clicking on '36 GB fileystem' in devices section of the "file explorer"; 
$mount dev/sda5; according to mtab, /dev/sda5 is already mounted on /media/8bda7c6d-bdb1-4ecd-b17d-4ab94c64eb2a;
But when running sudo update-grub, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:  try the boot repair CD.Boot with this CD and let repair the program your grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried,
the program starts in [LXDE](http://lxde.org/]), and then asks me the same as it did when I run it on Ubuntu (by running ubuntu from usb). I run the commands in the LXTerminal, and the second command still gives the same error...